# Angular.js, HTML List element

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova

Im starting with Ionic and Phonegap. I got list elements two class inside the html body

```
<body ng-app="todo">
<div class="list">
  <a class="item item-icon-left" ng-click="derecha()"  ng-controller="derecha"> Calama </a>
  <a class="item item-icon-left" ng-click="abajo()"  ng-controller="abajo"> Ollagüe </a>
</body>
```

in the app.js I got the following.

angular.module('todo', ['ionic'])

```
.controller('derecha', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
console.log("derecha");
});


.controller('abajo', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
console.log("abajo");
})
```

When I try to see it the browser these error appear:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module todo due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'todo' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/nomod?p0=todo
```

I had spent two days studying the issue but with no answers at all. Is there someone that could help me to call two differents functions using the two elements of a list?

thanks in advance 
--in

Comment: have you included your js script file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Failed to instantiate error means that angular is unable to locate a module, in this case a module called todo.
Make sure you have included the js file in which this module is defined and that it doesn't have any errors that would prevent the module definition to execute.
If you have any doubts regarding module definition take a look at the docs [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)

Edit: Tour code without the semicolon causing the problem:

```
   <!-- language: lang-js -->
  .controller('derecha', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
     console.log("derecha");
  }) // ; removed
  .controller('abajo', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
     console.log("abajo");
  })
```

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: but if I erease   .controller('abajo', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
console.log("abajo");
}). It works! So todo is connected well

Comment: Well I believe thats because you are introducing a syntax error, try removing the semicolon in the first controller declaration: <code>.controller('derecha', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
console.log("derecha");
})

.controller('abajo', function($scope, $ionicModal) {
console.log("abajo");
})</code>